# <stdin>:14:11: ERROR: [plugin: angular-css-resource] Could not resolve "open-sans/cyrillic-italic_300.woff2" issue while Update angular 16 to 17

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass, font-face

Got below error while updating angular V16 to V17.

[ERROR] Could not resolve "open-sans/latin_700.woff2" [plugin angular-css-resource]

```
<stdin>:581:11:
  581 │   src: url("open-sans/latin_700.woff2") format("woff2");
      ╵            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

You can mark the path "open-sans/latin_700.woff2" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which
will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in the bundle.
Preprocessor stylesheets may not show the exact file location of the error.

✖ Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy partial compilation mode.